# (1/1) InvalidArgumentException Driver [mails] not supported

Tags: php, email, laravel-5.4, sendinblue

Laravel 5.4 forgot password show this error

> (1/1) InvalidArgumentException
>
> Driver [mails] not supported.

I'm using laravel Auth and 
My mail driver is sendinblue and this is my `.env`

```
MAIL_DRIVER=sendinblue
MAIL_HOST=smtp-relay.sendinblue.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=xxxxxxxx@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=xxxxxxxx
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

SENDINBLUE_KEY=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

and `mail.php`

```
    'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER'),
      'host' => env('MAIL_HOST'),
    'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
    'from' => [
            'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'ejarati.softfruitsolutions@gmail.com'),
            'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Bianat'),
        ],
 'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),

    'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
```

I don't understand how to fix this